# Android Development Setup on Windows 8 Pro 64bit

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I have recently started the development for Android platform. For this I am using Eclipse (version details are listed in the end) on Windows 8 Pro x64 OS. I have 2 versions of java x64 available on my machine: 1.7.0_25 and 1.6.0_45.

Now the problem statement:

1. When I set java 1.7 as the system level default java version i get the following error:

   ```
   [2013-07-28 01:50:41 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger.
   ```

   The above message comes with different port numbers many time. I did the research on the net and the people were suggesting to fallback to the older version of java to resolve the issue, in my case I downloaded and installed 1.6.0_45. now the above DDMS error is gone, but there arises a bigger problem now.
2. The Eclipse closes suddenly all by itself no message no error displayed or reported on the UI. but when I looked into the eclipse log file, I found the error is raised due to some java related library is not functioning.

   ```
   Eclipse Version: Kepler Release (Build id: 20130614-0229)
   OS: Windows 8 Pro x64
   Java Version: 1.6.0_45 and 1.7.0_25 (latest while I am writing this post)
   Antivirus: AVG Internet Security 2013 without firewall setup.
   ```

Can anyone please help me find out the solution for the problem, so that I can setup my development environment with no issues.

Comment: Add adb.exe as a firewall exception and exclude your source folders from AVG.

Comment: I still get the same error of DDMS with the 1.7.0_25.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved from the android development on eclipse to Android Studio, so there is no more help required. I will recommend anyone else looking for the solution for the above problem to move the Android Studio too.